# What is uwphost.dll?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-store, .net-native

I'm trying to certify my UWP application for the Windows Store and I'm getting a message that several methods in **uwphost.dll** aren't compatible with the store.

```
API ExecuteAssembly in uwphost.dll is not supported for this application type. GammaFour.InvestmentManagement.Client.exe calls this API.
API DllGetActivationFactory in uwphost.dll is not supported for this application type. GammaFour.InvestmentManagement.Client.exe has an export that forwards to this API.
```

This is disturbing because I didn't explicitly add this library and have no idea how to fix the problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: How did you create the package for store submission? IIRC uwphost.dll is only included in debug packages (or when turning off .NET native compilation), so it should never be in the app package you'd use for submission.

Comment: It was the **Compile with .NET Native Tool Chain** on the Build tab (it has been turned off at some point).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UWPHost.dll is a helper library that Visual Studio adds to your package in scenarios where .NET native compilation is turned off (e.g. for debugging).

When creating a package for store submission, make sure .NET native compilation is turned on (it is on by default for Release builds). This should address your problem.